# How do I get specific days of te month in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example I have data in interval from '2020-01-01' to '2021-01-31' how can I get specific days from this months like first 2 days and last 3 days for each month.

Result I want:

| date | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| '2020-01-01' | x |
| '2020-01-02' | x |
| '2020-01-29' | x |
| '2020-01-30' | x |
| '2020-01-31' | x |
| '2020-02-01' | x |
| '2020-02-02' | x |
| '2020-02-26' | x |
| '2020-02-27' | x |
| '2020-02-28' | x |
| '2020-03-01' | x |
| '2020-03-02' | x |
| '2020-03-29' | x |
| '2020-03-30' | x |
| '2020-03-31' | x |

et cetera

Comment: Pls. tag your DBMS

Comment: Is that sample table data? Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Tagged DBMS. The table above is expected result, forgot to specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A date truncated to the first day of the month plus one month minus one day is the last day of that month. So

```sql
select * from the_table 
where 
 extract('day' from "date") in (1, 2) -- the first two days of the month
 or "date" between -- the last 3 days of the month
  (date_trunc('month', "date") + interval '1 month - 3 days')::date and
  (date_trunc('month', "date") + interval '1 month - 1 days')::date;
```